# Unable to install helm

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am unable to install helm locally on linux based aws server, i checked on helm docs and found below steps but got an error, need assistance

```
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
```

[image: error]
[image: error2]

Comment: What linux? Also that's the relationship between using curl and apt? Which one does not work?

Comment: Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
Both dont work.

Comment: sudo curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, but everything works as expected on Amazon Linux 2. Maybe ubuntu 20.04 is too old.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, then this might issue with SSL handshake with URL, will check on proxy

Answer (score 1):

`apt-transport-https` needed, see [here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/#from-apt-debianubuntu) for the the Debian/Ubuntu installation guide.

Comment: Yes followed the steps From Apt (Debian/Ubuntu) & it worked, now seeing below

Comment: helm version
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /root/.kube/config
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.9.2", GitCommit:"**", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.17.12"}

Comment: chmod 600 ~/.kube/config